# Defining different fonts for \title and \thanks in memoir

Tags: fonts, footnotes, memoir, titles

I wanted to change the font for the `\title` and `\thanks`. This can be done by adding the font in front of the text in whatever I want to change, e.g. `\title{\sffamily{My Title}}`.

I guess there is a smarter way, like for what I have done for my captions:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},textfont={small}}
```

So I don't have to define the specifications for the captions every time. Or maybe change the font for `\title` in my `\maketitle`-rules? I suspect there is a similar solution for `\title` and `\thanks`, but I haven't been able to find one, or figure one out by reading in the `memoir` manual.

For relevant stuff in my preamble is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Hope some of you savvy people can help me out!

**Edit:**

Here's what's needed to create my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article,twocolumn]{memoir}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\checkandfixthelayout
\RequirePackage{kpfonts}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newgeometry{left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,head=79pt}
%%%%%%
% Keywords
%%%%%%
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{Keywords:} #1}
%%%%%%
% \thanks
%%%%%%
% Maybe I can put something here???
%%%%%%
% Pagestyle
%%%%%%
\makepagestyle{paper}
\makepsmarks{paper}{
  \createmark{chapter}      {both}{shownumber}{}{ -\ }
}
\makeoddhead{paper}%
  {Published: \puB}%
  {}%
  {\sffamily\institution\hspace{0.1cm}\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{logo.png}}%
\makeevenhead{paper}%
  {Published: \puB}%
  {}%
  {\sffamily\institution\hspace{0.1cm}\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{logo.png}}%
\makeoddfoot{paper}
  {}
  {\thepage} %  {\thepage/\pageref*{LastPage}}
  {}
\makeevenfoot{paper}
  {}
  {\thepage}
  {}
\makeheadrule{paper}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
%%%%%%
% Dates
%%%%%%
\newcommand{\submitted}[1]{\gdef\suB{#1}}
\newcommand{\published}[1]{\gdef\puB{#1}}
\newcommand{\suB}{}
\newcommand{\puB}{}
\predate{\vfill\begin{flushleft}\large}
\postdate{\vfill\end{flushleft}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\huge\bfseries\sffamily\vskip 0cm}
\posttitle{\end{flushleft}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \maketitlehooka %before \title
    \vskip -1cm%
  {\@bspredate %
  \hspace{-0.9em}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{5cm}}
    Submitted: & \suB\\
    Published: & \puB 
    \end{tabular}
    \@bspostdate}
  \maketitlehookb % before \author
  {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
  \maketitlehookc % before \date  
  {\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}%
  \@bspreauthor %
  \@author %
  \@bspostauthor%
   \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.20\textwidth}%
    \centering
    \vskip2em\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo.png}%
    \vskip0em\sffamily\bfseries\institution
    \end{minipage}
    }
  \maketitlehookd % after \date
  \vskip 1em
}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{Title of paper}
\newcommand{\institution}{My University}
\author{%
First author\thanks{My e-mail}
\and 
Second author\thanks{\ttfamily{Their e-mail}}
}%
\submitted{DATE 1}
\published{DATE 2}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\maketitle\hrule
\vspace{10pt}
\begin{onecolabstract}
Some text for my abstract...
%\input{0-abstract.tex}
\end{onecolabstract}
\keywords{%
Please, let, me, pass
}\vspace{10pt}
\hrule\vspace{30pt}]
\saythanks
\pagestyle{paper}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section for intro}
\lipsum[1-1]
\chapter{Method}
\label{chap:method}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

My guess is that it's possible to change the font of all `\thanks`, instead of writing the font into the `\thanks{}`.

Comment: There is `\pretitle`, `\posttitle`, `\preauthor`, `\postauthor`, `\predate`, `\postdate` etc defined which can be configured to change the fonts of title, author and date.

Comment: Ahh yes. Good idea. I just added `\sffamily` to my `\pretitle`, and it worked! Any idea where I can do that for the `\thanks`? 
I tried with `\renewcommand{\makethanksmarkhook}{\fontsize{8}{11}\sffamily}`, but it didn't change the font.

Comment: @user38934: Do you want to change the font of the mark, or the actual note?

Comment: Change the font of the actual note - not the marker. Right now I just write `\thanks{\sffamily{Some text}}` for every `\thanks` entry. Hopefully there is a smarter solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) does "provide some flexibilty in the titling style of the document[;] user level commands are provided that can be changed to reconfigure the appearance resulting from `\maketitle`". These include

```
\pretitle
\posttitle
\preauthor
\postauthor
\predate
\postdate
```

For updating the `\title` font, add it using `\pretitle{<font>}`. However, consider the fact that some default `\title` formatting for `\title` is already set:

```
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
```

For updating the `\thanks` font, tap into `\makethanksmark` which is placed just before the `\thanks` text. One can either use `\g@addto@macro` to add content, or perform a `\let...\renewcommand` update.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\title{A title}
\author{An author\thanks{A note.}}

% Update font of \title.
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\sffamily}

% Update font of \thanks note.
\let\oldmakethanksmark\makethanksmark
\renewcommand{\makethanksmark}{\oldmakethanksmark\sffamily}
% ...or
% \makeatletter
% \g@addto@macro\makethanksmark{\sffamily}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

---

The following informal way of updating `\title` and `\thanks` to always include what you need might also be what you're after:

```
\let\oldthanks\thanks
\renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{\oldthanks{\sffamily #1}}
\let\oldtitle\title
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\oldtitle{\sffamily #1}}
```

Comment: I added a my preamble in my question, because I have tried placing your code in different places, but I can't figure it out. Where should it be placed, or does the placement not matter?

Comment: @user38934: I've updated the answer to include something simple that should work in your case. Both `\title` and `\thanks` are updated using the form `\let\oldX\X \renewcommand{\X}[1]{\oldX{\sffamily #1}}`.